# Getting IP addresses from an MPI program on a supercomputer

Tags: fortran, ip, mpi

I have the following MPI Program:

```
 program hello
    include 'mpif.h'

    integer my_pe_num,errcode
    call MPI_INIT(errcode)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,my_pe_num,errcode)
    print *, 'Hello from ', my_pe_num, '.'
    call MPI_FINALIZE(errcode)

 end program hello
```

It's fine.  Now I would like to get the IP address from each process to go along with the rank.  I looked at `MPI_Get_Processor_name`, but that's not what I want.

When I run this, it is via batch on a supercomputer.  The actual step that runs the program is:

```
mpirun -np 4 ./hello
```

Comment: The method is somewhat OS-dependent, and examples you find will likely be in C or C++.  Whatever method a program uses on the head node will likely work if done by rank on the compute nodes (but probably only one distinct IP address per node).  "Supercomputer" covers a wide range of platforms, some of which may not have IP addresses for individual ranks.

Comment: OK.  It is on CentOS.  I can read C or C++, just prefer working in Fortran, please.  Thanks for the good info.

Comment: I'm surprised you need IP's for each process. What's your use case? This sounds like an x-y problem to me... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You're right!  I tried the MPI_Get_processor_name, and am now trying to get ip addresses for the hostnames.  I see it in C but not Fortran.  Thanks, Ross!

Comment: *Why* do you want ip addresses for the hostnames?

Comment: note a host can have several IP addresses. I am afraid you have to write your own Fortran glue for `gethostbyname()`

Comment: It's for a training exercise.  Thanks to all!